# How to combine Arrayconstrain and Vlookup formula in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I created a slip format in Google Sheets and I would also print it afterwards.
These slips are numbered from 1 to infinity.

I need help in constructing the formula.

**What i created so far:**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MU_kBQgfyqgFuVet3hU6DW_WLuYwYYJ51uU-cB38gsQ/edit?usp=sharing

**What i wanted to happen:**
When I type the number in cell S1, it would also reflect the corresponding QWS No. in cell T2.

To do this, I was thinking that I should incorporate Vlookup (as what i placed in cell S2) inside the Arrayconstrain formula in column T. However, I don't know if it is possible though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Rather than using `VLOOKUP`, you can do this by running a `QUERY` instead.*

#### Forumla:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY('QWS Tracker'!A3:B, "select B where (A="&S1&") or (A="&S1+1&") or (A="&S1+2&")"),3,1)
```

#### Rundown of this Formula:

- Query the sheet `'QWS Tracker'!A3:B` for:

  - Values of column B where:

    - The corresponding cell in row A is either `S1`, `S1 + 1` or `S1 + 2`
- Contstrain the Array to length 3

#### References:

- [ARRAY_CONSTRAIN - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267036?hl=en)
- [QUERY - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)
- [Query Language Reference (Version 0.7) | Charts | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)